# When writing a C++ class, under what circumstances is writing custom copy and move constructors, and destructors necessary or advisable

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor, copy-constructor, move-constructor

When is it necessary and / or advisable to implement non-default

1. copy constructors
2. move constructors
3. destructors

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: almost never. let library types like `vector`, `shared_ptr` and `string` handle that for you. if you **need** to write a resource manager, remember the single responsibility rule.